# $http not displaying response in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

I am working on an angularjs app and the $http I am trying to setup is connecting with the php file and the header is showing a response that I echoed from php. My problem is:

1. php is not getting the data I send to it
2. angularjs is not displaying the php response on the page.

I built this based on a tut:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm

here is my angular controller

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'userServices', function($scope, userServices) {
    $scope.users = userServices.loginUser();
}]);
```

Here is my angular service

```
app.factory('userServices', ['$http', function($http, $q) {

    // return public api
    return ({
        loginUser: loginUser
    });

    /*
     * attempt to login user
     * returns user profile info if succeed or false if no match found
     */
    function loginUser() {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "../data/user.php",
            params: {
                action: "login"
            },
            data: {
                userName: "me",
                userPass: "pass"
            }
        });
        return ( request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    }
    /*
     * transform error response, unwrapping application data
     */
    function handleError(response) {

        // response should be returned in a normalized format
        // when errors are given by the server we send our formated error
        if(!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
            return( $q.reject("An unknown error occured"));
        }
        // use expected error message
        return($q.reject(response.data.message));
    }

    // for success we unwrap the application data from API response payload
    function handleSuccess(response) {
        return(response.data.message);
    }
```

Lastly here is my php file

```
if(isset($_POST['userName'])) { // 'userName' is not set
    echo '[{"message": "userName is '.$_POST['userName'].'"}]';
}  else {
    // php current returns this message in the header response
    // angular is not seeing this message
    echo '[{"message": "userName not set"}]';
}
```

Appreciate the help in the matter

Comment: What does the network activity look like on your browser's dev tools?  Is it going to the right Url?

Comment: are you meaning the php file path? Firebug shows a successful post with response message from the php file in question. Angular is just failing to pass it data values and catch the response message from it.

Comment: Your code has two issues: one is yours, one is of angular+php. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

**First**: PHP cannot process `application/json` Content-Type as input.

I had the same issue in my code. You have to switch to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type - don't know why is `json` the default way of angular serialization for http requests, but PHP -which is the most server side technology used for web pages- does not process that type, and gives empty data for `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

So you must pre-process your requests (we'll address this later).

**Second**: For your returned data. You are echoing:

```
'[{"message": "userName not set"}]'
```

Which is an array. So you must access it as:

```
response.data[0].message
```

instead of

```
response.data.message
```

**and you must ensure the response is json-typed** before echoing, so there's no doubt that angular will treat that as json:

```
//don't echo anything before this
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//... more code here
if(isset($_POST['userName'])) { // 'userName' is not set
    echo '[{"message": "userName is '.$_POST['userName'].'"}]';
}  else {
    // php current returns this message in the header response
    // angular is not seeing this message
    echo '[{"message": "userName not set"}]';
}
```

**Now let's take back what we left for later**: what will we do to send data from Angular to PHP? **Preprocessing**:

1. This is how I setup my module to preprocess **every** request to be in a format compatible with PHP.

   ```
   var index = angular.module("Application", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'], ['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
   }]);
   ```
2. There's a method to install preprocessing of data for each request. However it did not work for me. Instead, I passed to the `data` argument of `$http.post` a value converted by the following function (you can take it or must code one that follows your needs):

   ```
   var phpserializer = {
       __encode: function(name, value) {
           return window.encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + window.encodeURIComponent(value);
       },
       __isPrimitive: function(value) {
           return value instanceof Boolean || value instanceof String || value instanceof Number || !(value instanceof Object);
       },
       __isDate: function(value) {
           return value instanceof Date;
       },
       __indexed: function(prefix, property) {
           return prefix ? (prefix + '[' + property + ']') : property;
       },
       __serializeDate: function(value) {
           return {
               'day': value.getDay(),
               'month': value.getMonth(),
               'year': value.getFullYear(),
               'hours': value.getHours(),
               'minutes': value.getMinutes(),
               'seconds': value.getSeconds(),
               'milliseconds': value.getMilliseconds(),
               'timezone': value.getTimezoneOffset()
           }
       },
       __params: function(data, prefix, query) {
           angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
               var fullIndex = this.__indexed(prefix, index);
               if (this.__isPrimitive(value)) {
                   //objetos primitivos, valores primitivos (exc. undefined)
                   if (typeof value !== "undefined") query.push(this.__encode(fullIndex, value));
               } else if (this.__isDate(value)) {
                   //objetos fecha: metemos los componentes
                   //que son relevantes a la fecha
                   this.__params(this.__serializeDate(value), fullIndex, query);
               } else {
                   //datos tipo objeto o array, ambos iterables en angular
                   this.__params(value, fullIndex, query);
               }
           }, this);
       },
       params: function(param) {
           var q = [];
           if (this.__isPrimitive(param) || this.__isDate(param) || param instanceof Array) {
               param = {'value': param};
           }
           this.__params(param, '', q);
           return q.join('&');
       }
   };
   ```

   You must adapt this code to meet your needs (e.g. I use a custom serialization of dates, which will not -perhaps- be useful to you). This function will convert `{a: {b: 1, c: 2}, d: 3}` to `?a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d=3`
3. Finally, I use an abstraction ober `$http` to do POST requests:

   ```
   function ajax_post($http, data, $s, $q, target, params) {
       cancelCurrent($s);
       $s.canceller = $q.defer();
       return $http.post(
           target,
           phpserializer.params(data),
           {
               headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
               },
               timeout: $s.canceller.promise,
               params: params || {}
           }
       );
   }
   ```

   Which I customize later with the success and error callbacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I used most of your code and was able to get php to see the data I sent it and return my value through the header response, but angular only alerts an object for response. What is the $s parameter? I have it commented out right now (undefined)

Comment: I should note I have tried response.data[0].message, response[0].message which returned undefined and response.message returned "$digest already in progress" response by itself returned simply object

Comment: I take `$s` in the ajax function to be the `$scope`. `$http` and `$q` are literally those services. remember that's not a controller but an internal function I use in the project.

Comment: Perhaps those objects are undefined because Angular does not treat them as objects. Ensure that you send the `application/json` content-type in your php and will work.